# How to use vpython in spyder?

Tags: python, spyder, vpython

I am trying to use vpython, any way I can, but I'm failing...

First, I installed the Anaconda Python 2.7.10 on Win 8.1.
Then, I installed Vpython by typing into the command line:
conda install -c https://conda.binstar.org/mwcraig vpython

Then I tried 3 things:

(1) Double-click the "VIDLE for VPython" shortcut on my desktop. Nothing happens. I look at the target, which points to pythonw.exe.
I double-click directly on pythonw.exe. Nothing happens.

(2) I notice that there is also python.exe in the same folder, so I double-click on it, and get a command prompt. I type "from visual import *" and it seems to execute without error. Then I type "sphere()" and opens up a gray window titled "vpython" but it just hangs without ever showing me a sphere.

(3) Then I launched spyder, and typed "from visual import *", which seemed to execute without error. Then I typed sphere(), and it spits out the text "visual_common.primitives.sphere at 0x152ccb38" and another gray window pops up with the title "vpython" but it also hangs indefinitely.

How can I debug this situation? Thanks so much! I'd really like to show a simple vpython script in my physics lecture tomorrow...

Answer (score 0):

I know its late, but it might prove useful to others:

To run vpython 7 from an IDE you need to have Python 3.5.3+ installed. Note that for use in Spyder you  have to go to Run > Configure and specify "Execute in a new dedicated Python console" ( Vpython doesn't work in spyder 3.2.0).
This information can also be found at http://vpython.org/.

For questions regarding vpython I recommend you ask in the Vpython users google group.